# Odds of guessing a sequence of cards in order

Tags: probability, self-learning

For a deck of 52 cards, find the number m such that
$P$(by random guessing we get more than m correct guesses) < $1/10000.$
I was thinking along the lines of - if there is m correct guesses, there are $(52-m)!$ possible arrangements with a correct guess.
So the probability of m correct guesses is
$(52-m)!/52!=k$ and the solution is given by $k<1/10000$.
Is my reasoning correct? If not how to solve this problem?

Comment: For a little clarification: You have a deck of 52 different cards randomly ordered and you make 52 guesses for what each individual card is. Find the greatest $m$ such that $P(\textrm{You get more than m correct guesses})<{10}^{-4}$. Is this the problem you're after?

Comment: Yes. You have put it into better words. I will edit the question with your words to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, the problem asks for getting *more than* $m$ correct guesses, so you're looking for at least $m+1$ correct guesses? I think your idea is good, but you need to take into account that you don't know *which* $m+1$ guesses are going to be correct. There are $(52−(m+1))!$ arrangements for a particular correct guess.

Comment: I feel that the inequality suggests that $m$ is the upper limit of correct guesses.

Comment: Take the same problem but with 3 cards $\{A, B, C, D\}$ in deck and let $m$ be 1. Then lets say you guess $(A, B, C, D)$ in that order. You get more than $1$ correct guesses with $$\{(A,B,C,D),(A,B,D,C),(A,D,C,B),(A,C,B,D),(D,B,C,A),(C,B,A,D),(B,A,C,D)\}$$ There are $4!$ arrangements of the deck, so $p=\frac{7}{24}$. But ${(4-2)!\over4!}=\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: For the above example $p = 6/24$. Since $(A,D,C,B)$ is not a valid order. Also, $(4-1)!$ = 6.

Comment: $A$ is correctly guessed and $C$ is correctly guessed.

Comment: How is 'random guessing' defined for this question? _Example 1_: I randomly guess a 52-card permutation ahead of any card being shown. _Example 2_: Before each individual card is shown I randomly guess one of the 52 possible cards. _Example 3_: Before the first card is shown I randomly guess one of the 52 cards. Before the second card I randomly guess one of the 51 remaining cards, then one of 50, one of 49, etc. down to the last card which, because I count cards perfectly, I get right with 100% probability. These examples are all 'random guessing' but will give different answers.

Comment: @nickgard Before any card is picked, we guess a sequence of m cards and they have to be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three formulations

1. Suppose you guess the sequence of cards (either entirely at the start or just before each card is turned over).  You want more than $m$ of your guesses to be correct before you give a wrong answer. This has probability $\frac{(51-m)!}{52!}$ - almost what you wrote, but the question says *more than* - and will be less than $\frac1{1000}$ when $m \ge 1$, since $\frac{1}{52 \times 51}=\frac{1}{2652}$ is the probability you get at least two, i.e. more than one, correct before making an error, and is small enough.
2. You guess the full sequence of cards (a permutation of the deck) at the start and you want more than $m$ of any of your answers to be correct matches, not caring how many errors you make or when.  This is related to [rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)  and the probability will be less than $\frac1{1000}$ when $m \ge 5$
3. You guess each card before it is turned over, after taking into account the cards previously turned over,  and you want more than $m$ of any of your answers to be correct matches.  You will probably do better in this formulation as, for example, your $52$nd guess should be correct by elimination and your $51$st has a probability of $\frac12$.   The probability will be less than $\frac1{1000}$ when $m \ge 11$

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I will start learning derangement as it seems a nice way to represent these problems.